# How can i add transparent map view in camera view in android?

Tags: android, android-mapview, android-camera, augmented-reality

Hi I am developing an android application based on location services. Here i want to show the location near by the device in the map. My idea is showing map above the camera view. We can add surface view for camera and we can add views for that surface view. Like this way I want to add map view in surface view above the camera view. I need to rotate the map based on the direction. Please let me know is there any sample application for rotating map by direction and adding map view on camera view.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use a Framelayout where you put your 2 Views (CameraView and MapView) over themselfes.

And use the xml attribute alpha to make the MapView transparent.

Comment: Thank you for your response.Is it possible to make the map background as transparent. i just want to show street lines and location points. And one more request can i get rotating map with respected direction?

Comment: I guess it is possible. I would try writing my own MapView and instead of taking the images to display, take a single transparent pixel. Should work, but I never tried.